# Why could joining two Datasets and saving it to text file fail with NullPointerException?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using sqlContext data frames / scala and have been writing out some of this data successfully. I now need to do a right join to another table, which filters it down to only the data I am interested in. However, when I try to write this joined table, it results in a NullPointerException.

This works:

```
data
    .select($"id", $"text")
    .map(x => (x.getString(0), x.getString(1)).productIterator.mkString("\t"))
    .saveAsTextFile("/hdfs/filepath/output.tsv")
```

But this does not:

```
data
    .join(data2, Seq("id"), "right")
    .select($"id", $"text")
    .map(x => (x.getString(0), x.getString(1)).productIterator.mkString("\t"))
    .saveAsTextFile("/hdfs/filepath/output.tsv")
```

The stack trace I get is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:150)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:149)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1198)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1250)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1205)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1185)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
... 3 more
```

Running both of these...

```
data
    .select($"id", $"text")
    .printSchema
data
    .join(data2, Seq("id"), "right")
    .select($"id", $"text")
    .printSchema
```

..results in the same schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

And if I add `.show(5)` the tables look the same (with the exception that the joined one only contains my data of interest)

```
+-------+--------+
|   id  |    text|
+-------+--------+
|   1   |some... |
|   2   |text... |
|   3   |here... |
|   4   |foo...  |
|   5   |bar...  |
+-------+--------+
only showing top 5 rows
+-------+--------+
|   id  |    text|
+-------+--------+
|   1   |some... |
|   4   |foo...  |
|   5   |bar...  |
|   7   |other...|
|   9   |stuff...|
+-------+--------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

I have also tried a join to a different table: `data.join(data3, Seq("id"), "right")` and get the same NullPointerException error. Why?

Comment: If the "productIterator" is actually the thing causing the null pointer exception, then it must see the following List you are using as null: (x.getString(0), x.getString(1))

Comment: @TBowman that makes sense - but why would productIterator see the list as null only after the table join?

Comment: I also just tried `.take(1).foreach(println(_))` after the .map statement (in lieu of the saveTextFile) and in both cases the id and text print out, so the list is not null.

Comment: What's the Spark version you use?

Comment: What I am guessing is that you have id  in data2 that is not present in data and since its a right join, text field is null.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan - you are exactly right! I didn't think to look at this because I didn't think it possible - I created data2 as a subset of data1. But there are 3 null values. Now time to investigate why... :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from @RameshMaharjan, I realized that there were 3 null values after I joined data and data2. Turns out if you have null values then you will get a null pointer exception... :)

Anyway, 2 options I found to fix:

1: inner join instead of outer

```
data
    .join(data2, Seq("id"), "inner")
    .select($"id", $"text")
    .map(x => (x.getString(0), x.getString(1)).productIterator.mkString("\t"))
    .saveAsTextFile("/hdfs/filepath/output.tsv")
```

2: get rid of null values

```
data
    .join(data2, Seq("id"), "right")
    .where($"id".isNotNull)
    .select($"id", $"text")
    .map(x => (x.getString(0), x.getString(1)).productIterator.mkString("\t"))
    .saveAsTextFile("/hdfs/filepath/output.tsv")
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning me in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

(That might not be the definitive answer yet, but could not use comments to convey the idea)

---

> But this does not

The point is that you create a tuple only to destructure it immediately afterwards to get the values that might not exist.

I'd rewrite your code with the following:

```
data.
  join(data2, Seq("id"), "right").
  select($"id", $"text").
  as[(String, String)].  // <-- Added explicit type conversion
  map { case (id, text) => s"$id\t$text" }.
  write.
  text("/hdfs/filepath/output.tsv")
```

That should certainly pass without the exception since you simply concatenate two string fields and save it to a text file.

Comment: Thanks, Jacek - it's a good idea but I tried and see `value .saveAsTextFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String]`

Comment: Fixed the code. Sorry about that. I seemed to have copied your code with the additional type change with `as` without checking it out.